# What is ... and :?

Tags: syntax

Reading Maeder's *The Mathematica Programmer* and in section 4.6 I am interested in the following line:

```
Class[ class_Symbol, superclass_?ClassQ, variables : {_Symbol...}, 
  methods : {{_Symbol, _Function}...} | {} ] :=
```

What do the colons after *variables* and *methods* mean? Also what does the ... mean after _Symbol and after the list {_Symbol, _Function}?

My guess is that ... means any number of the given type, in this case symbols and lists of symbols and functions, respectively. My guess for : is that variables and methods must be of the form that follows the colon.

Comment: `:` means [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html)], and `...` means [`RepeatedNull`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedNull.html). You can always select these bits of punctuation in the _Mathematica_ front end, Right Click and select "Get Help".

Comment: Specifically here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/12

Comment: `sym : obj` or `Pattern[sym, obj]`
represents the pattern object `obj`, assigned the name `sym`. See the documentation for [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html)